# How do I merge a 2d numpy array with a structured array

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to know how to merge a 2d numpy array (n rows by m columns) with an existing structured array (with n rows).  This sample code shows what I am trying to do:

```
D = np.array([('a', 12), ('b', 14), ('c', 10)], dtype=np.dtype([('label','a2'),  ('ht', 'i2')]))

xxx =  np.array([[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[78,88,98]])

E = np.lib.recfunctions.merge_arrays([D, xxx])
print E
```

what I would like as a result is

```
[('a', 12, [1,2,3]) ('b', 14, [5,6,7]) ('c', 10, [78,88,98])]
```

I have tried converting xxx to a structured array first, and have also tried append_fields with a dtype specified, but havent had any luck in either of those two approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find `np.lib.recfunctions.merge_arrays`.  Maybe we have different `numpy` versions.  Rather than dig around for it, I'll do the merger myself, using methods that I've seen in other `rec` functions.

Your samples:

```
In [2]: D = np.array([('a', 12), ('b', 14), ('c', 10)],
    dtype=np.dtype([('label','a2'),  ('ht', 'i2')]))    
In [3]: xxx =  np.array([[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[78,88,98]])

In [6]: D.dtype
Out[6]: dtype([('label', 'S2'), ('ht', '<i2')])
```

Define a new dtype for `E`.  This could be built from `D.dtype`, but I'll just type it in.

```
In [9]: dt=np.dtype([('label', 'S2'), ('ht', '<i2'),
            ('xxx', xxx.dtype,xxx.shape[1])])
```

And a new blank array of the right shape and dtype:

```
In [11]: E=np.zeros(D.shape, dtype=dt)

In [12]: E
Out[12]: 
array([('', 0, [0, 0, 0]), ('', 0, [0, 0, 0]), ('', 0, [0, 0, 0])], 
      dtype=[('label', 'S2'), ('ht', '<i2'), ('xxx', '<i4', (3,))])
```

Now copy fields from `D` and `xxx`.  This kind of is common in the `rec` functions.  There isn't anything more streamlined for compound dtypes.

```
In [13]: for name in D.dtype.names:
   ....:     E[name] = D[name]    
In [14]: E['xxx']=xxx

In [15]: E
Out[15]: 
array([('a', 12, [1, 2, 3]), ('b', 14, [5, 6, 7]), ('c', 10, [78, 88, 98])], 
      dtype=[('label', 'S2'), ('ht', '<i2'), ('xxx', '<i4', (3,))])
```

That's your target, right?

---

For some reason I have to import `recfunctions` separately.  That's not usual for `numpy`.

```
from numpy.lib import recfunctions
```

When mentioning `merge_arrays` and `append_field`, you really should describe what didn't work, whether it was an error, or you didn't like the result.

`merge_array` does work:

```
In [35]: e=recfunctions.merge_arrays((D,xxx))
Out[35]: 
array([(('a', 12), 1), (('b', 14), 2), (('c', 10), 3), (('-1', -1), 5),
       (('-1', -1), 6), (('-1', -1), 7), (('-1', -1), 78),
       (('-1', -1), 88), (('-1', -1), 98)], 
      dtype=[('f0', [('label', 'S2'), ('ht', '<i2')]), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

It's just that the 2 input arrays are separate fields:

```
In [38]: e['f0']
Out[38]: 
array([('a', 12), ('b', 14), ('c', 10), ('-1', -1), ('-1', -1), ('-1', -1),('-1', -1), ('-1', -1), ('-1', -1)], 
      dtype=[('label', 'S2'), ('ht', '<i2')])

In [39]: e['f1']
Out[39]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  5,  6,  7, 78, 88, 98])
```

`append_fields` works for a simple addition, but not for `xxx` with 3 columns

```
In [57]: recfunctions.append_fields(D,'xxx',[1,2,3],usemask=False)
Out[57]: 
array([('a', 12, 1), ('b', 14, 2), ('c', 10, 3)], 
      dtype=[('label', 'S2'), ('ht', '<i2'), ('xxx', '<i4')])
```

Or I could turn `xxx` into a structured array, and append that:

```
In [60]: x1=np.zeros((3,),dtype=[('xxx',int,(3,))])
In [61]: x1['xxx']=xxx
In [62]: x1
Out[62]: 
array([([1, 2, 3],), ([5, 6, 7],), ([78, 88, 98],)], 
      dtype=[('xxx', '<i4', (3,))])

In [63]: recfunctions.append_fields(D,'xxx',x1,usemask=False)
Out[63]: 
array([('a', 12, ([1, 2, 3],)), ('b', 14, ([5, 6, 7],)),
       ('c', 10, ([78, 88, 98],))], 
      dtype=[('label', 'S2'), ('ht', '<i2'), ('xxx', [('xxx', '<i4', (3,))])])
```

Closer, but not quite right.  I could keep playing with these functions, but is it worth it?

---

These are equivalent, though `recursive_fill` handles more complex dtypes:

```
recfunctions.recursive_fill_fields(D,E)
for name in D.dtype.names: E[name] = D[name]
```

Here's a way of building `E.dtype` with recfunctions, but there's got to be something simpler:

```
dt2=list(recfunctions.flatten_descr(np.dtype(recfunctions.zip_descr([D,x1]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[(d,list(x)) for x,d in zip(xxx,D)]
```

gives

```
[(('a', 12), [1, 2, 3]), (('b', 14), [5, 6, 7]), (('c', 10), [78, 88, 98])]
```

and

```
np.array([(d,list(x)) for x,d in zip(xxx,D)])
```

gives

```
array([[('a', 12), [1, 2, 3]],
       [('b', 14), [5, 6, 7]],
       [('c', 10), [78, 88, 98]]], dtype=object)
```