# How to get matching rows from two n-dimensional arrays in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numPy arrays that have different number of rows and the same number of columns. The structure of every array - year, month, day, time, number_of_satellite, value_of_data. Every array has a different kind of data.

How can I compare these two arrays to get only common rows in both arrays, where the comparing parameter are the first 5 columns and then are two columns with coresponding values. For example:

```
A=[('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G06', 46.29)
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G12', 444.344)
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G14', -99.269)
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G20', 6.874)
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G24', 158.488)
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G25', -60.831)
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G31', -48.234)
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'R07', -6.243)]

B=[('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G06', '0.000')
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G12', '0.000')
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G14', '0.000')
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G24', '0.000')
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G25', '0.000')
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G29', '0.000')
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G31', '0.000')]
```

The result, I would like to get:

```
C=[('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G06', 46.29, '0.000')
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G12', 444.344, '0.000')
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G14', -99.269, '0.000')
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G24', 158.488, '0.000')
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G25', -60.831, '0.000')
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G31', -48.234, '0.000')]
```

I can do it using a loop, but it is not efficient solution, when you have arrays with 50000+ number of rows.

Comment: Are you wedded to using numpy?  When you're working with labelled tabular data, it's really a [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) problem.

Comment: Your arrays are 1d structured, not n-dim.  How do you do this in a loop?

Comment: Can you make any assumptions about order?  uniqueness?

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers!  @hpaulj I was doing double loop with "if" looking for the rows which are the same. It is working but as I have written it takes to much time :) I don't understand a little bit your question about order.   I try to use the solutions that are shown here :) Thank you a lot one more time :)

Answer (score 3):

In a backwater of `numpy` code there is an easy solution, `recfunctions.join_by`.

```
import numpy as np

A=[('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G06', 46.29),
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G12', 444.344),
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G14', -99.269),
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G20', 6.874),
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G24', 158.488),
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G25', -60.831),
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G31', -48.234),
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'R07', -6.243)]

B=[('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G06', '0.000'),
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G12', '0.000'),
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G14', '0.000'),
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G24', '0.000'),
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G25', '0.000'),
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G29', '0.000'),
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G31', '0.000')]

dt=[('a', 'S4'), ('b', 'S1'), ('c', 'S1'), ('d',float), ('e', 'S3'), ('f',float)]
aA=np.array(A,dt)
aB=np.array(B,dt)

flds=list('abcde')

from numpy.lib import recfunctions
mrgd = recfunctions.join_by(flds, aA, aB, usemask=False)
print(mrgd)
print(mrgd.dtype)
```

producing

```
[('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G06', 46.29, 0.0)
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G12', 444.344, 0.0)
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G14', -99.269, 0.0)
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G24', 158.488, 0.0)
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G25', -60.831, 0.0)
 ('2015', '1', '1', 0.0, 'G31', -48.234, 0.0)]
[('a', 'S4'), ('b', 'S1'), ('c', 'S1'), ('d', '<f8'), ('e', 'S3'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8')]
```

In the current organization `recfunctions` have to be imported separately.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33680606/901925

We'd have to examine the code to see how it is actually implemented.  And I don't know, without further timing, how the speed compares with the equivalent `pandas`.

---

With this small sample, `recfunctions` is faster than `pandas`, especially if the time required to create the dataframes is included.

```
In [302]: %%timeit 
   .....: a = pd.DataFrame(A)
   .....: b = pd.DataFrame(B)
   .....: c = pd.merge(a, b, 'inner', left_on=[0,1,2,3,4], right_on=[0,1,2,3,4]) 
   .....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 8.01 ms per loop
In [303]: %%timeit
   .....: aA=np.array(A,dt)
   .....: aB=np.array(B,dt)
   .....: aC=recfunctions.join_by(flds, aA, aB,usemask=False)
   .....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 3.35 ms per loop
```

Both are slow compared to numpy set operations like `in1d` (which don't attempt merging):

```
In [308]: timeit np.intersect1d(aA[flds],aB[flds])
1000 loops, best of 3: 326 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Use pandas for this:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame(A)
b = pd.DataFrame(B)
c = pd.merge(a, b, 'inner', left_on=[0,1,2,3,4], right_on=[0,1,2,3,4])
```

Where `'inner'` means to merge only if the key values are present in both arrays. The `left_on=[0,1,2,3,4]` means to use those columns as key values.

It gives the following result:

```
In: print(c)
Out: 
      0  1  2  3    4      5_x    5_y
0  2015  1  1  0  G06   46.290  0.000
1  2015  1  1  0  G12  444.344  0.000
2  2015  1  1  0  G14  -99.269  0.000
3  2015  1  1  0  G24  158.488  0.000
4  2015  1  1  0  G25  -60.831  0.000
5  2015  1  1  0  G31  -48.234  0.000
```